# WordPress plugin DB upgrade

Tags: plugins, database, upgrade

I am writing plugin. I have added 1 custom table in database.

Suppose my plugin's current version is 1.0
After few days i am upgrading plugin and now its version 1.2.
Same for after some time and now version is 1.3 and ..... 1.4

Now for every release of plugin version I have made some changes in database.

Than how can i upgrade database. I know about store db version in options table.

But i don't know because some user update his plugin from 1.1 -> 1.2, other is from 1.1 -> 1.4......... some is 1.2 -> 1.4..etc.. Than there is only way to add all conditions to code or any other solution is available?????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, no. But it's not particularly complicated. Just add a new `version_compare` block each time you revise the database:

```
$db_version = get_option( 'my_plugin_version' );

if ( version_compare( $db_version, '1.1', '<' ) ) {
    // Initial update code added in 1.1
}

if ( version_compare( $db_version, '1.2', '<' ) ) {
    // Additional update code added in 1.2
}

if ( version_compare( $db_version, '1.3', '<' ) ) {
    // And so forth
}

update_option( 'my_plugin_version', '1.3' );
```

This accounts for upgrades from any previous version, and only applies updates required to bring the db to the current version.