# Update User Role

Tags: plugins, user-roles, capabilities

I'm developing an plugin that adds an new user role (client role, for instance). This role only extends the admin role for now.

```
add_role(
    'client',
    __('Client'),
    get_role('administrator')->capabilities
);
```

Now i wan't to release an new version of the plugin that update the client capabilities and remove the `install_plugins` capability.

Roles are persistent, so i can't just update my `add_role`.

**My question is:** how can i manage an custom role, updating it's capabilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head, you should be able to do something like this:

```
$role = get_role( 'client' );

if ( $role && $role->has_cap( 'install_plugins' ) ) {
  // Role not updated yet, so update it.
  $role->remove_cap( 'install_plugins' );
}
```

`get_role()` returns a `WP_Role` object on success and `WP_Role::remove_cap()` calls `WP_Roles::remove_cap()`, which directly updates the option in the database. The `$role->has_cap()` check ensures that the code isn't run twice.

Running this in a function hooked to `init` should suffice.

Ideally you'd have a [database version option](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/159149/wordpress-plugin-db-upgrade/159151#159151) for your plugin which you could use to run some code exactly once per plugin update. Otherwise your code is executed again every time someone manually adds the `install_plugins` capability to your role again. That's not necessarily bad, but it could be prevented :-)

Code reference:

- [`get_role()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_role/).
- [`WP_Role`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_role/)
- [`WP_Roles`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_roles/)

Comment: Good explanation. For my plugin, the best choice is an database version manager. I will try to implement it.

Comment: I have another question that is related to this one, but about an specific hook. Can you check it? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/291134/hook-upgrader-process-complete-running-moment