# Hook (upgrader_process_complete) running moment

Tags: plugins, hooks, updates, upgrade

i want to use the `upgrader_process_complete` ([documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/upgrader_process_complete)) to check if my plugin was updated (to run some scripts).

My question is: when this action is triggered, WordPress is already running the new version of the plugin or it is just downloaded and i will need to wait the next request to get the latest version running?

The documentation says:

> *The upgrader_process_complete action hook is run when the download process for a plugin install or update finishes.*

But i'm not sure about this information. Anyone that uses this hook knows the answer?

Comment: When WordPress completes the core upgrade, it redirects you to the Dashboard. When you see the Dashboard, it's already the new version.

Comment: Thanks @MaxYudin , but i'm talking about the backend triggered hook. I'm trying to find if i will need to wait until the next request after the `upgrader_process_complete` action is triggered.

Comment: This may help you: [A Guide to the WordPress HTTP API: Automatic Plugin Updates](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-guide-to-the-wordpress-http-api-automatic-plugin-updates--wp-25181) and [WordPress plugin update hook – upgrader_process_complete](https://catapultthemes.com/wordpress-plugin-update-hook-upgrader_process_complete/).

Comment: Thanks @MaxYudin it helped a lot. I will need transients to transit the update status until next request.

Comment: In case you need the code https://stackoverflow.com/a/50914655/128761